# Find value from sub array within last 30 days using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to locate a certain value in a sub array using Mongoose.js with MongoDB. Below is my Mongoose schema.

```
const foobarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

foo: {
    type: Array, 
    required: true
},

comments: {
    type: Array, 
    required: false
},

createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
```

});

The value I am trying to get is inside `foo`, so in foo I always have one array at place [0] which contains an object that is like the below

```
{
    _id
    code
    reason
    createdAt
}
```

I'd like to get the value for `reason` for all records created in the last 30 days. I've looked around on stack overflow and haven't found anything I could piece together. Below is my existing but non working code

```
const older_than = moment().subtract(30, 'days').toDate();
Foobar.find({ ...idk.. req.body.reason, createdAt: { $lte: older_than }})
```

edit add mock document

```
{
  foo: [{
    _id: 'abc123',
    code: '7a',
    reason: 'failure',
    createdAt: mongo time code date now
  }],
  comments: []
}
```

curent code half working

```
const reason = req.params.reason
const sevenAgo = moment().subtract(7, 'days').toISOString()
Foo.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            "foo.createdAt": {
              $gte: sevenAgo
            },
            "foo.reason": {
                reason  
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            reason: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$foo.reason",
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ])
```

Currently returns blank array - no query failure - which is wrong it should return at least 1 document/record as that is what is in the DB that matches

expected mock data
[
{
  code: 7a,
  reason: failure
}
{
  code: 7a,
  reason:failure
}
]

Comment: Can you edit this question with actual sample docs & required o/p..

Comment: @whoami What docs do you want?

Comment: Documents in your collection ! I am a bit confused here *so in foo I always have one array at place [0] which contains an object* Do you mean `[[{}]]`?

Comment: @whoami I've added a mock document which should give you a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: @whoami Sorry for confusion on docs vs documents, I thought you meant docs as in documentation not docs as mongo documents

Comment: When you say *for all records created in the last 30 days* -> Do you wanted to compare input `older_than` with `createdAt` field inside `foo`'s object ? Also do you have two `createdAt` fields in model/schema one in root level other inside foo's object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213190/discussion-between-joshk132-and-whoami).

Comment: @whoami Yes want to compare with createdAt date inside foo as the other created date inside the model/schema is a different date/time due to processing times and a few other reasons.

Comment: You need to use `$gte` instead of `$lte`, try this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/R9caLQRI_93) if that's what you're looking for, let me know I'll make it as answer, Also can you confirm you'll always have only one element in `foo` array ?

Comment: Is it working or still having issues ?

Comment: @whoami Still not working sadly, I couldn't get it to work in the console (using mongo atlas as a DB host) so haven't tried it yet in my code. I removed the date part to isolate the foo/reason part and haven't been able to get it working yet.

Comment: So what is not working ? fetching docs based on date ? Did you test query in playground given above ?

Comment: @whoami I've removed the date part of the query to work on the foo reason part. So date isn't a factor right now. I tested a bit in the playground to see how your code worked but didn't input any actual data past the mock provided since I don't know if it's public or anything like that. As for why I think it might not be working with atlas, atlast uses find not aggergate so figure that has to be why so been trying to figure out how to do it with find.

Comment: you can't do that using `.find()` that's the reason why I've done it with `.aggregate()`..

Comment: @whoami Ah okay guess that was a big part of my issue then. I will try using aggregate in my code and see if that works. In your example I don't see how I could search for just a foo.reason like failure while leaving out the others. Am I missing how to do that?

Comment: @whoami I managed to get it to aggregate it and return the only result in the DB for foo. I am unsure how to get it to only return the one(s) I query for and also it is only returning the ID and the reason back not the whole document which I need. Do I have to break this down and do multiple queries after I get back the aggregate result?

Comment: @whoami I added my current code related to the question. It has my attempt at only matching the required documents via adding to the match selector which failed both in my code and in the playground you provided

Comment: Can you add required o/p for the given mock doc !

Comment: @whoami.  ??? Sorry don't understand what you mean

Comment: From the mock data provided in playground how does your expected o/p look like ?

Comment: @whoami Sorry for delay in response, I added mock data output in the OP. I duplicated one to show I want to get back all that meet a criteria, example `failure`